# symfony 2 bundle installation

Tags: symfony, bundles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

I  would like to install this bundle: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html
I am working on windows and i got installed the [github](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.7.10-preview20120409.exe&can=2&q=full%20installer%20official%20git)

I follow the steps on the first link. But after using : php bin/vendors install I get the following error: [ERROR](http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/3673/errorsfm.png)

I already read trough a couple of questions like this here, and i even added the PATH. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin), but still getting error. Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I remember, you can opt for either using the windows command prompt (and for that matter power shell) or a git shell shipped with msysgit (based on cygwin?). I assume that you either did not configure it correctly or opted for the latter. Alternative you could try github's windows client which provides a pre-configured git shell and might be easier to use: http://windows.github.com/

Comment: i give both suggestions a try thx