# Jenkins Git Release Failure

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, hudson, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to incorporate Jenkins Maven Release plugin with Git and the job is failing because it can't find the git executable.

My git repo is setup with ssh and I can execute the Git command on the Jenkins server.
I can run a build using Jenkins and everything is pulled down from the Git repo successfully.

But when I try to do a release, Jenkins fails to find the git command.  What am I doing wrong?

Jenkins Info:

- Version 1.504
- Git Plugin 1.2.0
- Git Client Plugin 1.0.3
- Running on Windows Server 2008

Git Installed on the Windows server - 1.8.1.msysgit.1

```
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git add -- pom.xml"
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.305s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 05 12:26:22 CST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/168M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\svctpsolap\jenkins_home\jobs\NBEntity\workspace\nbentity\pom.xml to C:\Users\svctpsolap\jenkins_home\jobs\NBEntity\modules\com.nb$nbentity\builds\2013-03-05_13-26-05\archive\com.nb\nbentity\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\nbentity-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project nbentity: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The git-add command failed.
Command output:
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Is git on your `Path` of the user running Jenkins?

Comment: It is on the path and Git can be executed anywhere in the command prompt.  I'm not sure on how Jenkins is executing the Git command

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the path to the `git.cmd` to the system `PATH` environment. Then restart Windows to take effect (restarting the Jenkins service alone is not enough).

Comment: for Jenkins Slave use case "restarting the Jenkins service alone is not enough" : I confirm that point! thanks