# installing perl module error

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install perl modules. When I type in the command

`cpan ABC::XYZ` (some module)

I am getting the error

`"'cpan' is not recognised as an internal or external command o,operable program or batch file"`.

How can I correct this?

I am using windows 7 system.

Answer (score 1):

`cpan` is just not in your environment, see that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493004/1102638

Comment: (or perl isn't installed, but that's perhaps a bit more obvious :))

Comment: Well, yeah, you can't add `cpan` to the environment until you install it :)

Comment: I know it sounds daft, but I have run into exactly that problem.

Comment: CPAN should be installed by default on Windows versions of Perl, such as ActiveState. On a more basic level, make sure the bin directory of your Perl install is in your path. Type "path" at the command line to check.