# Git is not accessible as a source provider from VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Can't nail what's missing with Git integration in VSCode (latest 1.23.1) on Windows 10.

Got Git 2.17.0 installed.

Got it in the system-wide Path.

Got this in my User Settings

```
 {
    "git.enabled": true,
    "git.path": "C:\\Git\\bin\\git.exe"
 }
```

Git is well visible in the built-in VSCode terminal:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\myself> git --version
git version 2.17.0.windows.1
```

Still nothing among "active source control providers", and no Git icon available there.

What's wrong?

**P.S.** None of this

[Git missing in VS Code – No source control providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609255/git-missing-in-vs-code-no-source-control-providers)

or that

[Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971624/visual-studio-code-cannot-detect-installed-git)

worked either.

Comment: Is there a git repository in your workspace?

Comment: not yet, I wanted to clone/check it out right from VSCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no repository in the workspace then VSCode will display the message

> There are no active source control providers

If you wish to clone a repository into your workspace you can use the command  `Git: Clone` described in [the VSCode doc page on source management](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol)'s section on [cloning a repository](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_cloning-a-repository)

Or to initialize a new repository you can use the similarly useful `Git: Initialize repository` command described in the [initialize a repository](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_initialize-a-repository) section of the same document (incidentally, this section describes the message you are seeing). This however has a matching button in the top right of the built in source control tab.

If you didn't already know, the command palette can be reached by using the keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

or

<kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply. It definitely works as you described, I was just puzzled by no visual evidence it is there, while some of the previous topics insisted there should be an icon indicating that. But whatever. It just works.