# Visual Studio Code does not recognize Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I just updated Visual Studio Code to v.1.19.0 and suddenly Git is not recognized. I can still perform everything from the terminal (cmd) window, but the *Source Control* tab is empty and I get:

> Git not found. Install it or configure it using 'git.path' setting"

This is what I see in the Output console:

```
Looking for git in: C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

In my settings I have:

```
"git.path": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\cmd"
```

which points to the location of git.exe

I am not sure why, but when I installed Git it placed it in the *AppData* folder instead of in *Program Files*.  Regardless, everything was working fine until this morning when I installed the update.

If it helps, I am on a Windows machine with Windows 10 64-bit OS and Git version 2.15.1.windows.2.

Why is Visual Studio Code not seeing it?

Comment: What is the location of git? maybe you just need \\ on the end of the path

Comment: You were on the right path, but this did not work.  I had to add git.exe at the end of the path as VonC suggested below.

Comment: Likely canonical (2015, 36 answers, and 221 votes): *[Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971624/)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2017: Try setting `git.exe` instead of the parent folder:

```
"git.path": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe"
```

This is what I needed in my own VSCode User settings:

[image: user settings for git.exe]

---

More recently, VSCode 1.50+ (Sept. 2020), I mention in "[Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63966054/6309)" that you can add multiple paths.

That helps when your [VSCode settings are synchronized](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) across your machines, but your Git is installed in different places on said machines.

And don't forget, with [VSCode 1.60+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69161206/6309), `"git.enabled": true`.

Comment: brilliant.  it worked :)  SO would not let me accept the answer yet, but I will in a few minutes.  I wonder why this happened suddenly.  I have the path in my environment variables.  It seemed that it used the path from there up until now.

Comment: Did not work for me. I set the git.path setting, however, every time I start VS Code I still get "Git not found. Install it or configure it using the 'git.path' setting.". I'm on version 1.37 of VS Code.