# Git commands in Visual Studio Code Terminal are not working, yet they work on the cmd prompt

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, terminal

Error when trying a Git command in cmd:

> The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I need this to work in the integrated terminal on Visual Studio Code!

I've already tried editing the path variables and the settings in Visual Studio Code. Nothing works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code does not recognize git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849984/visual-studio-code-does-not-recognize-git)

Comment: I already tried the solutions in that question. It doesn't work. I think I'm having a different problem! I'm not getting that error. I'm getting a different. It's not saying that git isn't installed, it's saying that 'git' is not _recognized_.

Comment: Likely canonical (2015, 36 answers, and 221 votes): *[Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971624/)*.

Answer (score 6):

"Not recognized" is normally the way terminals politely tell you they don't know what you typed means.

If you can use Git from a command line, then it's installed properly. You can use `where git` or `which git` depending on your command line to find the path of the functioning Git (if those don't work, please specify your terminal type in the question).

Once done, open Visual Studio Code, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to open settings and type `git path` in the search. Add this path, and you should be able to use Git in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It also helps to try restarting VS Code after updating settings.

Comment: Please note: 1. That's a comma, not a full stop in the shortcut to open settings "CTRL + ," 2.  You may need to replace the backslashes with forward slashes or escape the backslashes with another backslash. 3. If you have multiple VS Code windows, close all of them and then re-open for the changes to be made, reload a single VS Code window will not work if you have multiple.