# Error "'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to clone a project of GitHub into Visual Studio, so I go to New Terminal and type:

```
git clone [CLONE WITH SSH LINK]
```

and it shows:

> git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

However, I have already installed Git and Git is set to *Enabled* at Visual Studio settings.

Why does this error occur, and how can I fix it?

And how can I set/change the path of Git in Visual Studio...

Comment: `git` is not in the search `PATH` of the environment that is trying to execute it (and no absolute path is not being used).

Comment: @OndrejK. Plz tell me how to set path

Comment: This is likely about [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), not [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio). Nowadays, it is statistically always Visual Studio Code, never Visual Studio (thanks for nothing, Microsoft marketing). "New Terminal" is a menu command in Visual Studio Code (menu *Terminal* → *New Terminal*). There is also an entry in *Settings* in Visual Studio Code by the name *"Git. Enabled"*

Comment: But this is very likely a duplicate. There are known problems getting Git to work together with Visual Studio Code (in its built-in terminal window - which may be different from a CMD, PowerShell or [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) window). It could also depend on the version of Visual Studio Code. ***What is the canonical question?***

Comment: Candidates: *[Git commands in Visual Studio Code Terminal are not working, yet they work on the cmd prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58189196/)*, *[Git is not recognized in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69375464/)*, *[Git is not recognised in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50639459)*, *[Visual Studio Code does not recognize Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47849984/)*, and *[Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971624/)*.

Comment: The last one (2015, 36 answers, and 221 votes) may be the canonical.

Comment: Likely canonical for non-program-specific (2010, 42 answers, and 600 votes): [Errror "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Though "[cmdlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#Cmdlets)" in this question could suggest it is for Windows.

Answer (score 9):

#### Reinstall Git and reopen the editor

I solved the same problem by reinstalling Git.

And refreshed *npm*.

Then I closed the editor and reopened it.

Comment: What editor? [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)? [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio)?

Answer (score 8):

The reason behind it is that you might have not added the *Path* environment variable. So here are the steps for that.

Go to *Environment Variable*. Click on to the *Path* variable, *Edit* and add it to the path given below:

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin`

`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and close your terminal. Now open the terminal and check the command. You're looking for e.g. `git --version`.
It gives you the version you have installed.

Comment: On Windows, presumably? The question is probably about [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), not [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio). Though it could still be on Windows.

Comment: It is odd that the installation hadn't added paths automatically, but adding manually worked. My prior git installations were adding paths automatically.

Comment: This was the issue for me. Don't know why it did not add path variables automatically. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just reopened Visual Studio right after installing Git and that solved the issue for me! Just make sure to make it default for Visual Studio and allow third party command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

***BRIEF:* Run your editor, such as vim or vscode, with Administrator privileges (after installing git from git-scm.com)**.

> **Error "'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35023434)

Comment: i improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the bin and cmd file paths for the GIT program file in the environment variable. Find the environment variable by searching in your computer to add the file paths. Afterwards just restart your terminal.

Comment: Didn't Mohammed already say this nearly two years ago? Please don't repeat answers.

Comment: Yes Mohammed did. Thanks a lot for the feedback. I just felt I could give my version hopefully simplify for a someone new in tech.