# Why is Visual Studio Code not recognizing Git?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to upload my React app to my GitHub repository, but Visual Studio Code won't recognize a Git command.

I have Git on the PC. The path to Git is correct, and I checked multiple times. I have installed [GitHub Pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub#GitHub_Pages) through the Visual Studio Code terminal.  I have also added the required changes to file *package.json*. Now when I run `git init` in the Visual Studio Code terminal, it throws an error that "git" is not a recognized command. Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

This is the Git path in Visual Studio Code - "git.path": "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe". It is correct.

*Git Enabled* is checked as well.

File *package.json* edits under the first {} "homepage": "http://greardrear.github.io/messenger", is added and under scripts added "predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build", .

And when I try to do "git init" or "git remote add origin", I get this message in the Visual Studio Code terminal:

```
 git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How can I fix this?

PS. I have tried all of the "fixes" to this issue I could find. I have also tried changing the path to "git.path": "C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe" which also didn't work.

Comment: Likely canonical (2015, 36 answers, and 221 votes): *[Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971624/)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comment of [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64179658/6309), check first if simply restarting the PC would help.

PowerShell might need that to fully recognize the Git for Windows installation.

That or [reinstall Git for Windows again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63750388/6309).

---

Note that I do also mention in "[Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63966054/6309)" the Visual Studio Code 1.50 (September 2020) new feature:

> Support multiple values for the `git.path` setting

That can help when you are using Visual Studio Code with settings synchronized on multiple machines, with Git installed in different paths on said machines.

And don't forget `"git.enabled": true`.

Comment: Oh wow, apparently i was so cought up in the moment i didnt think of just restarting.... Thank you @VonC

Comment: No problem. 25 years in computer engineering, and "did you try to stop, restart it again?" is still as effective as ever ☺️

Comment: When a Windows program is installed that changes the `PATH`, there is a message that the installer can send such that running applications pick up the new value. Either that is not being done, or the programs in question which are not picking up the changed `PATH` aren't handling it.

Comment: E.g. under the NSIS installer system, the `EnvVarUpdate.nsh` script is used for updating environment variables. It sends a `WM_WININICHANGE` to the `HWND_BROADCAST` handle, with a particular parameter, and waits with a 50 second timeout.

Comment: @Kaz Interesting, thank you for the feedback. Do you have a documentation link to illustrate that? Would that apply to the OP's question?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, download and install the latest Git implementation from the link below:

https://git-scm.com/download/win

Then you have to add environment variables. Go to *System Environment Variables* and add the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin

C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and close your terminal. Now open the terminal again and check the command you're are looking for, i.e., `git --version` (it gives you the installed version).

Comment: Is it [actually called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows/72341522#72341522) *"System Environment Variables"* or has this been copied from somewhere else? What version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio terminal window - the default shell is powershell. Now if your git-bash setup is working outside of VS Code using git-bash app, then you need to setup the VS code - terminal - default shell as git-bash.

Here are the steps:

1. In VS code, open the terminal window under the code section.
2. You see tabs like OUTPUT, TERMINAL, GITLENS, DEBUG CONSOLE etc. On the extreme right you should see a "+" sign and that's a dropdown.
3. When you drop down you will see multiple options - default is powershell, others are command prompt, git-bash, java-debug terminal etc. You can choose git-bash to resolve the issue shown here.

Comment: This would benefit a lot from some editing to add paragraphs and formatting (such as using an actual numbered list). Can you [edit] this to make it easier to read?