# Git command not recognized even after installing NPM packages

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code

I am working on a little program that has a repository on GitHub. I have my Visual Studio Code open and I type the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/EXAMPLE/URL
```

The URL is not a real one, just an example. It gives me the following error:

```
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git clone https://github.com/EXAMPLE/URL
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried to add environment paths on Windows according to another Stack Overflow question but got the same error.

Comment: Where are you running this command?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am running this command inside of visual studio code

Comment: How are you running the command inside vs code? What are you using to run it?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I go to the menu terminal and click on new terminal, and then I type the command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686488/git-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)

Comment: Make sure first that it works *outside* VS Code, in a regular command prompt. That rules out if it's VSCode-specific or PATH-specific. Make sure you added the correct path in PATH environment variable.