# Git is not recognized in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to initialize Git in Visual Studio Code, but it is giving me errors. I already have it included in my path.

```
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git init
```

Comment: Go to Settings and search for "path". It will give you an option under "Git" to set the path to the executable. In the `settings.json`, the key is `"git.path": ""`.

Comment: "*I already have it included in my path.*" Which path and what exactly did you put in the path? Does the `git` command work _outside_ of VS Code?

Comment: Likely canonical (2015, 36 answers, and 221 votes): *[Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971624/)*.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have *Git/cmd* PATH included in environment variables,
**Restart Visual Studio Code**

Or...

Append *Git/cmd* to PATH in environment variables

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```