# Can't create multiple branches for Git in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I've worked with Git and VSCode before, and done so together; but I never tried to create a secondary branch **(The one that isn't master)**, so today that I decided to do so, I create a new branch called *test*, and VSCode shows me I'm working *in the test branch*, nothing bad here.

The problem comes when I try to navigate between my branches **(test and master)**; there is just one: *test*.

[image]

I have tried several methods, but none of them work; and yes, I have the [path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971624/visual-studio-code-cannot-detect-installed-git) for VSCode and Windows configured properly, so it isn't that.

Also as you can see on the SS above, in the console it shows this:
`fatal: ambiguous 'test': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

If I understand it correctly, that means ***it doesn't even recognize*** that the branch exists (Please forgive me if I misunderstood it, I'm not good at Git)

**Question:** Does someone know how I can correct this *interesting* behavior? I've been stuck with this for hours and haven't gotten anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is weird, after posting this I thought of using the *actual Windows cmd* and write Git in it, so I went with this:

```
$ git checkout -b master
```

Basically I re-created the `master` branch via commands.
Before when I asked it to show me the existing branches it would go like this:

```
$ git show-branch
No revs to be shown.
```

But after I executed the `checkout` command, it spits:

```
$ git show-branch --I replaced the test branch, for the afk, it's the same thing--
! [afk] Added html
 * [master] Added html
--
+* [afk] Added html
```

Which if I am not mistaken, says `afk` is now the master branch, and `master` is now a sub-branch... It's still bad, but now it **does** show both branches in VSCode:

[image]

So apparently, ***the solution is to manually create at least 1 branch in the console and then you can continue doing so with VSCode without problems.***

Still, I would like to know if someone has a better answer :).