# It looks like Git is not installed on your system. - VS Code

Tags: git, github, error-handling, visual-studio-code

I would like to ask your help to fix this error on my VS Code: "It looks like Git is not installed on your system."

1. I reinstalled Git and VS Code as well on my computer.
2. Checked, Git uses VS Code as default.
3. Changed the setting.json on VS Code (File/Preference/Settings...) with the proper "git path" from Command. (where git)
4. Also restarted the computer.

It looks like, that I am logged in to my GitHub on VS code, but when I want to clone a repo, I get again this message:
"It looks like Git is not installed on your system."

Thank you in advance for your help and time!

Comment: What operating system is this on?

Comment: What output do you see if you type `git --version`

Comment: This previous post could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973715/11246056

Comment: @JDługosz it is on Windows 10

Comment: @evolutionxbox it is git version 2.31.0.windows.1

Comment: is git project folder and your vs code project folders are same?

Comment: thanks, @CygnusX I went through all the comments from the link you referred to, just before I made the post. I continue the research.

Answer (score 0):

> with the proper "git path" from Command. (where git)

The usual trick is to put in that setting the full path, *including* `git.exe` itself.

That is:

```
 C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe
```

Not:

```
 C:\Program Files\Git\bin
```

And I prefer using VSCode in a session where the %PATH% references `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`: that alone should be enough (no need to use the setting)

I usually set:

```sh
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
```

Then I launch VSCode, without any Git issue

Comment: thanks, @VonC, right, I managed to mess my setting.json, but from here I could repair it:
 https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/.vscode/settings.json

Comment: @Melinda Well done. As long as your `%PATH%` references the parent folder of `git.exe`, VSCode should not have any issue finding `git`.

Comment: about the set, I am not 100% sure where to write. Is it in the Command after C:\Program Files\Git\bin>   ?

Comment: I would recommend instead to make them persistent by modifying your Windows User environment variables settings: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/121664-set-new-user-system-environment-variables-windows.html