# How to use git commands in Visual Studio 2019 Integrated Terminal

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to use git commands (i.e. git commit -m, git status, etc.) in the Visual Studio 2019 Integrated Terminal in Windows? I am currently getting the following error:

[Error when running 'git status' in VS2019 Integrated Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwlbE.png)

I was able to create a git repository and push to GitHub using the 'Git' dropdown menu, so I was under the impression that git was installed. However, I am a junior developer who learned in a Node.js environment using VSCode on a Mac and am used to using git commands in the VSCode Terminal.

Apologies if I am missing something obvious or if this question has been answered elsewhere. Thank you in advance.

Comment: On a similar matter with VS Code, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29973715/11246056