# How to use Git in VSCode's terminal? How to fix "The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a problem using the terminal in VS Code. I can't install anything on it.

I always face errors like this:

```
The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+ git <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/error-git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code cannot detect installed Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971624/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

As [Shaheerez said in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72515669/2745495), Git is not installed or its installation directory is not included in the system's `PATH` environment variable.

Here's how you can fix this issue:

- This command will display the current value of the `PATH` variable.

  ```
  echo $PATH
  ```
- Locate the installation directory of Git on your system. It is
  typically located under the "Program Files" directory on Windows or "/usr/bin" on Linux/macOS.

  - For Windows command prompt or Git Bash:

    ```
    export PATH="<git-installation-path>:$PATH"
    ```
  - For Windows Powershell:

    ```
    $env:Path = "<git-installation-path>;" + $env:Path
    ```
- Verify Git installation

  - To confirm that Git is recognized, close and reopen VS Code's Terminal. Type the following command and press Enter:

    ```
    git --version
    ```

Once you've followed these steps, you should be able to use the `git` command without encountering the "not recognized" error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can use Git normally outside of the VSCode Terminal. I'm also assuming you're on Windows based on the error message.

If so, make sure you're using the correct terminal.

1. Go to Settings -> Features -> Terminal
2. If you're on Windows, check the `External: Windows Exec` field.

If you can't use Git on your terminal, maybe you should also update your `PATH` variable. Include the path to the Git executables:

- `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\`
- `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\`

Comment: thank you for your answer. problem was fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think the git is not installed on your system.

You can download the installer from: https://git-scm.com/downloads.

Also, check that Git is included in the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a couple of things that cause this issue so let's walk through and debug what going on, try these steps:

### Check if Git is installed

1. In Visual Studio code, open a new terminal ( `` cmd + ` `` or `` ctrl + ` ``) and try entering this command: `git --version`
2. If you get an error saying *command not found* then let us try re-downloading git. [Click this for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) or [Click this for Mac](https://git-scm.com/download/mac) and follow the instructions. Just about every OS has an easy command to run such as `brew install git` for mac
3. Make sure to close and reopen all terminals and VSC after downloading, attempt the command `git --version` again, and hopefully, you will not see another error.

still having issues? Then let's check your PATH

### Check PATH for Git

1. open the terminal and type `echo $PATH`
2. Inspect the output from this command and check if you see git included.
3. If git is not included then use this command to add it to path `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/git` (you might need to change the /usr/ section as your machine might have different names for usr)
4. Not that git is in path, finally lets again try `git --version`

Comment: The error in the question is definitely coming from Windows powershell. Since the error would be encountered only by users on Windows, then `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/git` is not going to work because that's only for Unix/Unix-like systems.