# What is the difference between Git for Windows and Github Desktop?

Tags: git

As a programming neophyte, I have recently installed Github Desktop on Windows 10. However, upon using npm, I have discovered that some packages, like [bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower), require the user to install [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/).

My questions are: What is the difference between using Github for Desktop's installation of git and using Git for Windows? Would it be necessary to uninstall my current git and Github Desktop installation in order to to adjust my git command-line tools? If so, how should I proceed?

Comment: So many contradicting opinions, why did they (git folks)  have to make this so confusing - wasted enough time on this b.s. already !! Others https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297340/why-was-git-installed-in-appdata-instead-of-program-files are saying one is dependent on the other and not to use the one suggested here

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Would it be necessary to uninstall my current git and Github Desktop installation in order to to adjust my git command-line tools?

No both are completely independent.

- [git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) delivers MSys2-based Git builds (see "[How are msys, msys2, and msysgit related to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309)")
- [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) embeds a fixed (older) version of git-for-windows, in quite a complex path (`C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<sha1>`), and you cannot change it easily: "[How to update git version from GitHub Desktop on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703716/6309)"

You can safely install git-for-windows in addition of GitHub Desktop: both will ignore each others.

Answer (score 5):

[GitHub for Windows](https://desktop.github.com/) is a GUI interface for [`git`](https://git-scm.com/about). You can see a list of other GUI interfaces for `git` [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis).
If you have `Github for Windows` working then you also have `git for Windows` installed.

Comment: do you mean to update `git for windows`? You can simply install it from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads) to get the latest version.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: I installed git as "Use Git from Git Bash Only", and now I need "Use Git from from the Windows Command Prompt". I was wondering how to change it.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to simply reinstall. Atleast that's how i've done it in the past.

Comment: Thanks. However, I think I've accidentally done two installs on my laptop. Should I uninstall my most recent install?

Comment: In other words, how would I properly reinstall it? I'm not too computer-savvy.

Answer (score 5):

[Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io) includes "Git BASH" (uses MINGW64) and "Git GUI" (git-gui).  There is folder context menu (windows shell integration) to access these.  Includes the latest release of git.  It is not set up to access GitHub by default, but you can clone an existing repo from a source location.

[GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) ([formerly GitHub for Windows](http://haacked.com/archive/2015/10/29/git-shell/)) is a more streamlined GUI.  Uses PowerShell for git command line.   The version of git it includes [lags the latest release.](https://desktop.github.com/release-notes/windows/)  "Before you set up GitHub Desktop, [you must already have a GitHub or GitHub Enterprise account.](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started/installing-github-desktop/)"  You log in with your account, your GitHub repositories are automatically detected.

Answer (score 0):

A clarification: GitHub Desktop does have the PowerShell as the *default* shell, but you can go into Options -> Default Shell and change the shell to 'Git Bash'.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the hyperlink and it should be obvious:
Github Desktop is just a GUI for Git [Git-scm GUI options for download](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)

In my current Github Desktop I can navigate to **Tools and Options** >> **About Github Desktop** >> **Release Notes** and it shows supported git utilities 
These are older versions than are available on Git.