# Are Git and GitHub Desktop completely independent applications?

Tags: git, github

Some months ago, I installed GitHub Desktop (Version 2.8.2 x64) for Windows on my Windows 7 machine. I used GitHub Desktop to manage versions of my thesis, written in LaTeX, between my local machine and the GitHub cloud.

Now, an educational workshop on Python/Shell/Git I'm attending in a few weeks instructs me to install Git for Windows ([gitforwindows.org](https://gitforwindows.org/)).

Is it true that **"Git for Windows"** ([gitforwindows.org](https://gitforwindows.org/)) and **"GitHub Desktop for Windows"** ([desktop.github.com](https://desktop.github.com/)) are completely independent applications?  Will installing "Git for Windows" now, months after installing "GitHub Desktop for Windows" cause problems/interactions?

Answers to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428099/) seem somewhat contradictory. [This answer from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35129798/794233) seems to say that the two applications are independent of one another, but I want to make sure that five years later this is still the case.

Comment: If you already have the `git` command-line utility installed as part of Github, there is no need to install it a second time, though (in fact doing so will probably only lead to confusion. But I am not familiar with Github Desktop; maybe it's purely click and drool).

Comment: @tripleee Do you have any idea how I can tell if `git` is installed on my Windows machine?

Comment: Search for `git.exe` or (less reliably) type `git` at the CMD or Powershell prompt.

Answer (score 3):

`git` is a command-line tool that manages git repositories. You can invoke it from the command line and it will modify your git repository as you want to.

`GitHub Desktop` is a graphical application that provides a GUI for some git operations. You can commit, push etc using GitHub desktop but it doesn't have the whole functionality of git

GitHub desktop uses git under the hood in order to perform those operations. It is a graphical wrapper for those operations. You can even [look at the git installation inside of GitHub desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34565238/10871900).

But from a users perspective, `git` and `GitHub Desktop` can be seen as different applications for interacting with git repositories.