# How to tell if I have git on my Windows machine

Tags: windows, git, github

I'm running `GitHub Desktop for Windows (Version 2.8.2 x64)` on my Windows 7 machine.

How can I tell if `git` (i.e., [the command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67709996/794233) that manages git repositories) is installed on my Windows machine? If so, How can I tell which version of `git` I have?

Answer (score 3):

Open command prompt and run

```
git --version
```

If git is still shown as an unidentified command, try adding it to the [PATH variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/git-installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows)

Comment: What if `git.exe` is installed but not added to `%PATH%`?