# git is not recognized as an internal or external command windows - already tried to change the environment variable

Tags: git

I got the following error, git is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
I read in some forums that i need to add the /bin & /cmd paths to 'System variable' 
I've done that but am still running into the same error. Already restarted by computer. Ideas?

Comment: We need more information about your setup. Also, how do you know git is installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: I don't think you have correctly set your PATH to point at your git installation.

Comment: Type `echo %git%` from the Command Prompt.  What do you see?

Comment: I downloaded the Git desktop application

Comment: also typing 'echo %git%' gives me %git%

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue , I had setup the environment variables but still was not able to use git from command window . **Finally it worked when I added the path variable value to**

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

**instead of**

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

This will also be populated automatically if you select the option of use GIT from command prompt as shown below during your installation process .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6TNX.png)