# Getting 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command when I type git clone url in command prompt

Tags: github

I am trying to clone a project from Github using my command prompt with command git clone url(of project) but I am getting 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command error

Comment: If you are using Windows you have to add Git to your PATH settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command even with the PATH variable set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250015/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-even-with-the-path-va)

Answer (score 1):

If you are windows user and if you  haven't installed git yet you can install git from the following link [https://git-scm.com/downloads] .After that you can use the git bash instead of the command line

This tutorial may help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_Clau1bYco