# 'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command in windows server

Tags: php, windows, composer-php, environment-variables

I am using windows server 2008 os. i download [composer setup.exe](https://getcomposer.org/download/) and install to my PC . when I try `composer install`  . I getting an error:

> 'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

eg:-

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\shop>composer install
'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My environment variable PATH is shown below:

```
C:\xampp\php\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
```

Comment: in my case close vscode and it resolved but if open new tab in terminal not working

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi perfect..!! just close vscode

Answer (score 67):

For anyone coming here from Google who are facing the same issue. I just managed to solve this issue after all the other "solutions" other people suggested didn't work.

I installed Composer properly and the Environment variable was set but it just wouldn't work.

In my case composer is installed in `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin` and this is exactly what is in my `PATH` Environment variable. After messing around a bit trying to fix it I saw that under `System variables` under `PATH` there is something called `PATHEXT` I opened that and added `;.PHAR` to the end of it. So it ended up like this:

[image]

And this is what my `PATH` is now:
[image]

I closed all file explorer windows and command prompts and started a new CMD and ran `composer --version` and it worked!

I hope this helps someone facing the same issue as me.

Comment: this worked! Just curious, why do we need to add `;.PHAR` to the `PATHTEXT`?

Comment: @indago I can't be certain since I got this fixed by just randomly messing around but the reason I thought about adding .PHAR is that there is a Composer.phar inside the composer directory that I believe is what runs when you use composer commands , so when I saw that it's not there I added it and it immediately fixed the issue. Glad you got it sorted as well!

Comment: for me just restarting cmd (as admin) was enough

Comment: thanks, that's the exact problem i got after installing on Windows 11

Comment: the other thing i realize is that path to composer must be **higher** in list, than path to php. hope this will help someone.

Comment: I was using it in VSCODE and I had to close it once and open again to work

Comment: Fixed it for me on a Windows 11 laptop, thank you

Answer (score 23):

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Close your current terminal and open a new one.

Comment: You do not need to restart your computed, simply close your current terminal and open a new one.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem, I kept repeating the composer installation until it was resolved this way:

1) Download the composer installer (.exe) and put it on C:/XAMPP.

2) Run the installer by just clicking next till the end.

3) Open command-line (cmd) and cd to your project directory (C:/XAMPP/htdocs/myproject) and type composer and see if you have it installed.

4) It should work now, let's say you want to install a PHP framework from your project directory: `cmd=>composer require slim/slim "^3.0"`.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem .
In my case i used the command "php composer.phar " instead of "Composer " and it worked .

Answer (score 5):

just paste " echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat "  This in your Terminal where you install composer and Boom you get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use complete composer path instead of `composer install` 
eg:- `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer install" instead of "composer install`

Better still, add `"C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\"` to your environment variables, so that you can use `"composer install"`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows. Similar to Punit khandelwal's answer.

1. [Download and run composer setup](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
2. Copy `composer.phar` to `c:/composer/composer.phar`
3. Create a new file `c:/composer/composer.bat` with:

   @ECHO OFF
   php "c:/composer/composer.phar" %*
4. Add `c:/composer/` to your system [Path environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493004/667903)
5. Add `.PHAR` to your system PATHEXT environment variable (below the Path variable)
6. Close & reopen your VS Code/CMD/Power Shell

You can now run `composer` commands from the command line on Windows without receiving the message:

> 'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

```
If u can't find composer file than follow only 2 steps
1- Download composer file from [https://getcomposer.org/download/]<click on Composer-Setup.exe>

2- Install above file at your project root dir. and give second path is your php.exe file and finally solve this issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use
like this

C:\jay\xampp\htdocs\zoho1>php composer.phar require zohocrm/php-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You Just Don't need to worry about this if you have installed composer using **Command-line installation** than this problem will occurs.

So my suggestion is to download **.exe** file by visiting this link https://getcomposer.org/

And also after download using this link you don't need to use **php composer.phar** instead of composer only

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in installing the composer command in cmd but when I closed all windows file explorers and again run this command "**composer global require laravel/installer** " from "**[https://laravel.com/docs/8.x**"](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x**%22). It just installed without any error

Answer (score 0):

remove all your playings with composer path in **path** variable
go to https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer

and find  **Composer-Setup.exe** link to that exe.

Answer (score -3):

I can solve this problem easily without do anything.

Suppose I'm going to create a project in my desktop and facing the problem which you have shown in the description. now follow the step.

Project folder on desktop

[image: Project folder on desktop]

Step 1: go you your CMD(Command Prompt) of your Computer

[image: command canvas]

step 2:Select the folder by command here like image (cd/desktop/example folder)

[image: Select the folder on CMD]

Step 3: After select the folder now write the command which you want to do like screenshot . you can see Im writing the command for laravel.

[image: composer command]

done, just easy step you can work anything from here and you can see downloading and being prepare for the project

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T34i.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kcDP.png]