# 'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.5

I have installed the composer also and the path is also well defined but when I type composer update then the following error appears.
'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Path:
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin

F:\xampp\php

C:\Users\THEE NES\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

Comment: Did you try running it in a new command prompt instance?

Comment: yes i tried in new command prompt but it is giving same error

Comment: Does it work if you run the command from within the folder you have installed composer? Also can you please show us the Path environment variable value and the path which you have installed composer?

Comment: Did u restart computer after installing composer?

Comment: you have to check the directory where you have installed composer and run it in same directory.

Comment: Did you follow the [Installation instructions for Windows](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows)?

Comment: thank you all It starts working

Comment: @THEENES which was the problem?

Comment: I restarted my computer

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command in windows server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724594/composer-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-windows-serve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to run it in this way because you may not have installed it globally:

```
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer update
```

If it still doesn't work you have to restart `Windows Explorer or your computer` not only `cmd`