# Vim in command prompt on Windows 10

Tags: vim

I wanted to use Vim on the command prompt, but it gave

> vim is not recognized as an internal or external command

I tried searching for a solution and found that I should edit the user specific environment variable 'path', but it still gives the same error. What can be the solution?

Comment: What exactly did you add to the `path` variable?

Comment: Actually i selected 'browse directory' and selected the location of vim i.e C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/error-git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 28):

Go to the file location, and double click *install.exe*. That will open cmd.

If it asks you "Do you want to uninstall", type <kbd>N</kbd> and then type <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: How does this magically work ? Yet  D is not among the options .

Comment: The underlying issue wound up being Run As Administrator for me but this helped me to expose it

Answer (score 14):

Install vim again and make sure to check the box of "create .bat files" option when installing

Answer (score 6):

> Actually I selected 'browse directory' and selected the location of Vim i.e., `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim`

You need to locate the directory that contains `vim.exe`. If you use the default installation options (and latest available version), that would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80`.

Note that there's also a 64-bit version of Vim for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem of the installer on Windows 10!

The installer tries to write some files into *C:\WINDOWS*, but if you install without administrator privileges, those files cannot be written. However, the rest of the install works and so you think everything is fine.

Try to restart install.exe as an administrator!

Answer (score 3):

First, open Power shell and set alias for canonized commands (Windows 7 and above):

$ Set-alias vi "\path\to\gvim.exe"

$ Set-alias vim "\path\to\gvim.exe"

Answer (score 1):

unistall everythingn then
follow the guide on:
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/install-vim-text-editor-on-windows
and make sure to get the full installation
it will work in the CMD after that make sure to run it as admin
i had the same issue

Comment: Although this isn't a "proper" answer, this did work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When installing, put it to vim itself to create the bat path file on windows.
This was my solution to this problem