# Commands not working on Git Bash

Tags: git, bash

Hi i am willing to use Git Bash for app dev, however whenever i start it, it gives me couple of 'bash :export:' lines and not even the clear/clrscr commands work.
I am using a Windows 8.1 machine (6.00 gb ram, 1 TB - just so you know). I have tried the following:

- uninstalling-reinstalling git
- Using Git as CMD prompt

Below is the screenshot of the Terminal window:

[image]

Output of echo $PATH

[image]

This is my current PATH env variable:

C:\Users\Madhukar Jain.npm-global\node_modules\express;C:\Users\Madhukar Jain\AppData\Roaming\npm;%APPDATA%\Roaming\npm\node_modules.bin\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;

Comment: can you share output of  `echo $PATH`  ?

Comment: @PS. made the edits. You can check. The User name in my pc is Madhukar.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: @PS. checked all options. None work. Added both cmd and bin folders with the mentioned syntax. Resarting bash, still yields the same results.

Comment: try `set PATH=C:\mingw\bin;%PATH%` and then try running commands.

Comment: bash: fg: %PATH%: no such job

Comment: I checked out the **bin** folder of Git which consists of bash, git and sh shells. Could i use it from there? All commands work perfectly in those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the PATH is completely messed up. Are you using custom profile/rc file such as ~/.bashrc , ~/.bash_profile , ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile ? If yes you need to check whether the contents are syntactically correct. From the errors I feel that there are few issues with special characters such as spaces. You may have to use double quotes properly to clearly differentiate the directories in the PATH.

Comment: This is my PATH variable:  
C:\Users\Madhukar Jain\.npm-global\node_modules\express;C:\Users\Madhukar Jain\AppData\Roaming\npm;%APPDATA%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;

Comment: also since i have just reinstalled Git bash, i did not touch any of those mentioned files.

Comment: Turns out there was an 'export PATH' statement in my .bash_profile file. Apparently that remains untouched even after you reinstall git. Erasing its contents helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: check with this export PATH=$PATH:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin

Comment: The issue persists.

Comment: Answered by asatsi