# 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command in my angular project

Tags: git

I am getting this error.I added environment variable path also. Please help['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2FRP.png)

Comment: how did you install git?

Comment: Just a possible catch: The console where you are trying to run git was already open when you installed git (assuming it's windows)? If that's the case, then even if installation modified PATH, the PATH variable for that session hasn't been modified. Can you show us the output of this? ```echo %PATH%```

Comment: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\Code;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Hi\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Code;;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score -3):

download git for your windows and install it. Refresh or restart system