# Can't clone git repository after installing latest version npm

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I just downloaded and installed **node** and the latest version of **npm**.
When I'm trying to clone git repository I get

> "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error

I tried installing git specifically from npm and it seems to install some packeges but while trying to clone still see the same message.

any idea how to work it out?

Comment: You need to set the path for GIT. Check out this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Was already in the path. Git was not properly installed, after installing git it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git isn't installed via npm. The package you found does something with git repos (don't know, never used it - just a quick glance on its description), but it doesn't install git.

To install git on linux, https://git-scm.com/download/linux

To install git on windows, https://git-scm.com/download/windows

To install git on mac, (you may have guessed the link) https://git-scm.com/download/mac