# 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file even after adding to PATH

Tags: python, git, subprocess

I am a beginner in python. I have written the following python code:

```
import subprocess
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
process = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'status'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, cwd='my\git-repo\path',shell=True)
stdout_str, stderr_str = process.communicate()

print (stdout_str)
print (stderr_str)
```

Upon execution of the python script, I get the following output:

```
b''
b'"git" is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n'
```

I have added '..../git/bin' to my PATH variable, and since then git commands run fine in cmd.exe. Since 'shell=True', I thought this would run too.

I can't seem to get a hold of the issue. Help appreciated.

Comment: I don’t believe you that this code will produce *that* error message.

Comment: @poke yeah I had added results from another thing I tried. Sorry about that.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I ran into the same problem using this as part of a build chain. My script works fine when run on commandline, but as soon as it runs in the build step it can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to GIT PATH issues. Once, I updated the PATH properly in Windows Environment Variables and restarted CMD, I didn't face this issue.
Further info can be found at ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

Because `git add*` is not correct.  `git add *` is, however.

Comment: Sorry about that. But the real issue is that it doesn't recognise 'git' at all

Comment: `b''
b'\'"git add *"\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n'` --> with your suggestion too

Comment: Oh ok, I'll keep trying to figure it out.