# How to clone git repository in tensorflow

Tags: git

Facing following issue:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\venkat>git config clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Did you try googling?

Answer (score 2):

if you need to clone the repository use just 
`git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`

'git' is not recognized mean that  either you don't have git installed in your machine/computer or  the path variable is not set properly.

Comment: How to install git? or how to set path variable

Comment: visit https://git-scm.com/downloads  download the git which compatible with your system win or linux.

Comment: Im facing this after configuring git :   (tensorflow) C:\Users\venkat>git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models
fatal: destination path 'models' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: did the git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow  initial command worked?

Comment: "fatal: destination path 'models' already exists and is not an empty directory"  this issue is because the current directory your going to clone hava a folder called 'models'. git clone github.com/tensorflow/models command getting a confilit  because it also gointo create a folder called 'models'

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have git installed?

If the answer is yes, then in Windows, Git recommends use the [git bash console in Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) instead the Windows Command line.

- **`git config clone` it's not a valid git command**

If you want to clone a git repository use: `git clone <url_repository>` in your case:

`git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`

Comment: Hey I used (tensorflow) C:\Users\venkat>git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Still facing prblm

Comment: have you installed git? If so, try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command