# "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Env Detail:
Angular CLI: 6.1.3
Node: 8.11.3
npm version: 5.6.0

When I am trying to create an Angular project by executing `ng new Project-name` I am getting

```
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

instead of 'project name successfully created'

[image: command prompt]

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/786

Comment: how to add Git to PATH environment variable?Can u help me pls?@jonrsharpe

Comment: @FaiyazSayeed try uninstalling Git and reinstalling it. I recall it had an option in the installation process to add it to PATH.

Comment: @FaiyazSayeed try http://www.chambaud.com/2013/07/08/adding-git-to-path-when-using-github-for-windows/

Comment: thanks all,issue is resolved

Comment: Likely canonical (2010, 42 answers, and 600 votes): *[Error "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/)*.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check whether GIT is installed on your system. If not installed then install Git by downloading from below URL and install

https://git-scm.com/

2. Close your command prompt or visual studio code or any editor you are using and reopen it.
3. Create new angular application and it will work as expected.

Comment: Why would GIT be required to create a new app?