# git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in angular2

Tags: git

I was tried to make a new workspace for Angular2 project. I was creating this workspace on Node js command prompt. I have tried many times but get the same error.

'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please let me know how to get rid of this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: @BillP Could you please tell me the steps that I need to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with angular or npm. install git in your system it is not installed properly.

Comment: Can you please share the link for that?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an angular error, but a git error.

There may be two causes making this error:

1. Git is not installed on your system. Which, in case, install it from [here](https://git-scm.com/).
2. Git is installed on your system, but the path to the program is not set on your system. You can confirm that it is installed, and then add the path variable to it by going to System Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> system variables -> PATH

and then add the following path: `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd`

Hope this solves your issue.