# Unable to do SSH using Command Promp \

Tags: c, linux, ssh, popen

I am trying to establish SSH connection to a remote server to execute some command. I require to take CLA in my final program, so I'm trying to execute from Command Prompt. A sample code is given

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PATH_MAX 128

int main(void){

    FILE *fp;
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    fp = popen("ssh user@HOST \"command\"", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
       /* Handle error */;

    while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
    printf("%s", path);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The code execute fine using DevC++ but when I execute same from Command prompt it does not execute giving following message "**'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**"
I tried both **system("some command") and popen()**. Both work fine in DevC but give same message when executed from Command Prompt.
I'm having MinGW installed **gcc version 8.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3)**

Comment: This is not an issue with your program, but with the `%PATH%` environment variable.

Comment: Where is `ssh` installed? Is it in the Windows system `PATH`?

Comment: So the program is working fine and you're just asking for help with running ssh on Windows? How is that a programming question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: I have checked path variables and it exists already **C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\**. Infact if i directly go to command prompt and establish/run SSH connection, it works fine. Only trouble i am facing is while trying to do the same through C program from Command Prompt.

Comment: Thanks all, finally resolved the issue by adding path under System as well as User Variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SSH.exe` needs to be in the Windows `PATH`.  When the program is running, it might not be running under your profile.

It is possibly running under a system profile that does not have the same `PATH` defined.  You could have the program check and/or update the `PATH` or have it run under your profile specifically.

Comment: The purpose of this forum is to provide resolution.  Please add the solution or delete the post.

Comment: Thanks all, finally resolved the issue by adding path under User Variables. So i guess the problem was the program getting executed under User profile rather than System profile.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that even though the required path was present under System variables but, the program gets executed under User variables. So just by adding the same path (i.e; **C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH**) under User Variables solved the issue.