# In Windows, "Rails new" does not create all the files and folders, stops at -> run git init from "."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, new-operator

When I type -> rails new test_app, it only does the following -> 
create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."

I was able to run this command successfully (where it created all the folders and files needed in a rails app) in my c:\users\ directory, however was not able to run it anymore after that.   I have also deleted all rails related files in that directory and retried, but have had no success.

Please help.

Comment: Thanks for the advise!  I will try it

Answer (score 4):

Install git from [Git-Scm](https://git-scm.com/download/).

Enter `git --version` in command line if it returns version info go ahead and run

```
rails new projectname
```

If `git --version` throws error in command prompt as 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Add environment variable for git. Refer [Stackoverflow link to add environment variables for git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)