# ‘rails new’ command does not create the app folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-18.04

> Summary:
>
> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS; Rails 6.0.2.1;  ruby 2.7.0;
>
> ”rails new myapp” creates GemFile, .gitignore etc.. but doesn’t create
>   app folder

I have been successfully using Rails (5.1.6) on a cloud development environment (Cloud9), but wished to set up a local development environment.

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I then followed an online resource to guide me through the installation of RVM, Ruby and Rails itself. Everything appeared to install correctly (as demonstrated by the version checks below).

On running the command `rails new myapp` I expected to find the full suite of Rails folders and files created, but only found the 6 files shown below. Why has the app folder with its associated files not been created?

(I repeated this with Rails 5.2.0 and Ruby 2.5.1 and met the same issue)

```
simbed@simbed-ThinkPad-T410:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]
simbed@simbed-ThinkPad-T410:~$ rails -v
Rails 6.0.2.1
simbed@simbed-ThinkPad-T410:~$ sqlite3 --version
3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57 0c55d179733b46d8d0ba4d88e01a25e10677046ee3da1d5b1581e86726f2alt1
simbed@simbed-ThinkPad-T410:~$ yarn -v
1.21.1
simbed@simbed-ThinkPad-T410:~$ cd environment
simbed@simbed-ThinkPad-T410:~/environment$ rails new myapp
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
simbed@simbed-ThinkPad-T410:~/environment$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, see if git is properly installed.
[In Windows, "Rails new" does not create all the files and folders, stops at -> run git init from "."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442185/in-windows-rails-new-does-not-create-all-the-files-and-folders-stops-at-r)

Otherwise I recommend you to create a new directory like `rails_projects` and cd into `rails_projects` then do the `rails new myapp` command. It's possible the directory your currently running the rails new command in already has an initialized rails app.

Comment: Git was not installed. I find it curious that neither https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html nor other online guides state that Git needs to be installed. After running sudo apt install git, the rails new command worked as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @DanSimBed your solution worked like a charm , i wouldn't had figured it out too as it's not mentioned anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

- `mkdir myapp`
- `cd myapp`
- `rails new .`