# Missing files on new Rails project startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I'm trying to start a new ruby on rails application and any newly created projects results in missing folders.

I've tried this on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 (VM) with the same results. I must be missing something but I can't find it, can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

I can verify I have installed:

Ruby 2.6.3

Rails 5.2.0

Nodejs 10.18.1

When I make a new rails project with

`rails new test-app`

The following files are made

```
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
```

I've worked with Rails before and there should be many more folders such as an app, bin, config, db, etc. The created directory is also not acting like a rails directory (probably due to the missing content), any rails commands while inside the directory just result in a rails usage statement.

If anyone could explain to me what is going on or how this happened that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try installing git.

Run `git --version` in the command-line to check if it is installed.
If that returns an error, then refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) previous question.

You should also create a new directory, and run `rails new` from there.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think that would work, but everything seems to be resolved and back to normal! Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually I was talking about this to a friend for some time, the current theory is that when the .gitignore was being created, it failed (since I didn't have git-?/something was corrupted-?), the rest of the project creation failed from that point.