# Getting Error creating Nativescript shared project about missing .gitignore

Tags: nativescript

I am attempting to create a new code sharing nativescript app with Angular.

Per the documentation found here: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project

I have installed Nativescript and can create a non codesharing project just fine.

Here are the steps I have taken to get this error:
Created a folder I want this project to be in
Navigated to that project in command prompt and entered the following:
ng new -c=@nativescript/schematics test --shared

And I receive the following error
Path "/__dot__gitignore" does not exist.

I have tried adding a .gitignore file in that folder and that doesn't do anything.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I had to add a few path variables found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: Fixed it.
I had to add a few path variables found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command