# why does my command prompt showing like this?

Tags: node.js, git

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 14.16.1 (ia32) and npm.

C:\Users\Arthi>git---version
'git---version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Arthi>
```

Answer (score 1):

as said by @Tanner Dolby in comment  you should try `git --version`[image: just see this]

If the problem exists then you should install `git` properly
It is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493004