# Cannot create flutter project in vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program of batch file.
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...

`vscode`
move up flutter/bin

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have github desktop. But for use git-bash, try download the git framework:
https://git-scm.com/downloads. After installing, try to use the git command. Let me know if it worked.