# The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: git, powershell

```
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.        
At line:1 char:1
+ git remote add origin https://github.com/rehmat11872/gs9django.git
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: git is not in path of PowerShell

Comment: Likely canonical (2010, 42 answers, and 600 votes): *[Error "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/)*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/error-git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

While installing git and git bash, you might have unchecked `Add to Path`. I recommend you to reinstall git and continue with default settings by clicking `next>next>....>install`.

One side tip. Please don't keep your github repos empty. If you will be adding code in the future, then create repo when you want to push your code for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Git portable is missing from your machine. You can try choco commands to install this, & This would fix your issue

```
choco install git.portable
```