# I have a Terminal problem in vscode how do i fix

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, terminal, command

I am trying to upload an Github project and idk how so I tried a video, but the result is:

[image]

That is:

```bash
PS C:\Users\BRQL\Documents\Github vscode> git.init
git.init: The term 'git.init' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
+ git.init
+
+~~~~~~~~~~
+ Category Info
~
: ObjectNotFound: (git.init:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['git' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 2):

The proper command is [`git init .`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init), not `git.init`

The latter syntax is not recognized by `git`.

---

Note that is is best to `git init .`, meaning to initialize a new Git repository in the current local folder for a *project* folder.

Your current folder is `Github vscode` (from `C:\Users\BRQL\Documents\Github vscode`).
Unless your project is to develop VSCode itself, it is better to come up with an actual project name (here, for instance, "myProject"), and type instead:

```
git init myProject
```

That will create a `C:\Users\BRQL\Documents\Github vscode\myProject` in which you can start add/commit files.

---

As an alternative, you can also use (for local projects linked to a GitHub repository), the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://cli.github.com/) command (after [installation](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation=) and [authentication](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)).
Specifically: [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create)

```bash
mkdir myProject
cd myProject
# create a new remote repository and clone it locally
gh repo create myProject --public --clone
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install **git** first
you can download from https://git-scm.com/downloads
and

```
git .init
```

is not a git command.

git initializing commant is

```
git init
```

you can check the other commants of git from http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/common-git-commands.html

Answer (score -1):

The easies way for a beginner to get a new Github project working on there local machine is to create it on Github first and then `clone` the repository with

```
git clone url-of-repo
```

You then get a working repository copy in a subdirectory with the name of the project (as given when created).