# The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet in android studio

Tags: android, powershell, git-for-windows

When I try to use git in Android Studio terminal, I get this error:

> The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:1

[image]

Comment: The error message you quoted here is a PowerShell error, not a Git or Android Studio error.

Comment: Related (2010, 42 answers, and 600 votes): *[Error "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have git installed on your pc then add git to environmental variables.

Link: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/git/add-git-to-path-on-windows/