# Not responding Git init comment in Visual Studio code terminal?

Tags: c++, git, github, terminal

> Not responding Git init comment in Visual studio code terminal  .  I write a c++ program in visual studio that code I will send remote repositories but can't send because Git init comments not work  I'm see the only this error

"......\project> git init [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo4dB.png)

```
                   git : The term 'git ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet function ,script file , or operable program. check the spelling of the  name, or if a path was included , verify that the path is correct  and try again At line :1 chat:1
```

+ git init

+~~~~

CategoryInfo  :    ObjectNotFound:    (git:String) [] , CommandNotFoundException

+FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommendNotFoundException

### I write this code

```
#include<iomanip>
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
      bool accountCreated;
    if (accountCreated) {
        double amount;
        cout << "\nEnter the amount to withdraw: $";
        cin >> amount;
        if (amount > 0 && amount <= balance) {
            balance -= amount;
            cout << "\nWithdrawal successful. Your new balance is: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << balance << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "\nInvalid amount or insufficient funds. Withdrawal failed.\n";
        }
    } else {
        cout << "\nNo account exists. Please create an account first.\n";
    }
}
```

[https://screenrec.com/share/O4aTrL6NFt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo4dB.png)   request to solve this problem

Comment: Have you set git in the environment variable? [Error "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492979/error-git-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Either you do not have git installed or it is not in your path.